# Access a HashMap variable in c++

Tags: java-native-interface, hashmap

There is a HashMap variable "AA" in my java class "PMS". Now I want to access "AA" in a cpp file. I use JNI to resolve this. Here is my code:

```
jclass clazz=env->FindClass("com/pms/PMS");
jfieldID field=env->GetStaticFieldID(clazz, "AA", "Ljava/util/HashMap");
jobject objPackages=env->GetStaticObjectField(clazz,field);
```

But I get "java/lang/NoSuchFieldError", that is "AA" cannot be found. Then I try this:

```
jclass clsPackages=env->FindClass("com/pms/PMS$AA");
```

This time I get "java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError".  How should I do?

Comment: Please provide the declaration of field `AA` from the Java source. Is it really declared `static`?

Answer (score 1):

I think the second line in your code should be:

`jfieldID field=env->GetStaticFieldID(clazz, "AA", "Ljava/util/HashMap;");`

Semicolon at the end. It's part of the syntax. I forgot why.

a

Comment: Yeah, it worked. I am so careless and I forgot Semicolon. Thank you very much.